# Rijndael algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm

I want to work on the Rijndael algorithm using C#. Can anybody help me with this please?

Comment: Yes, but it spelled as Reindhal

Comment: Indeed - you've already used *two* alternative spellings; Reindahl vs Reindhal.

Comment: Rijndael was accepted as the algorithm for AES, so searching for "AES" is likely to turn up considerably more results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean the Rijndael encryption algorithm - in which case [RinjdaelManaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx) would be of use. The MSDN documentation (previous link) has examples, or there are lots of other references, for example [see here](http://www.osix.net/modules/article/?id=411).

I see (comments to other reply) that you are looking at implementing this yourself... some thoughts:

- don't
- why?
- don't

Unless this is **purely for interest**, stick to the existing implementation. It will eat time, and potentially introduce security weaknesses. I can't think of a good reason to rewrite this.

Comment: If at all possible, try to change your design to use a higher level abstraction layer like SslStream for data in transport or something KeyCzar for data at rest. There are just too many things to get wrong if you do things yourself.

Answer (score 9):

sorry guys, but I just can not resist

from http://www.moserware.com/2009/09/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced.html
[image]

Comment: ;) To be clear, when I drew that scene I was referring to writing your own version of Rijndael/AES. Using the .net AesManaged or RijndaelManaged might be ok, but as I mentioned in the comments on that post, you're *much* better off if you can design your program to use a higher level layer like SSL/TLS so that you don't have the chance of messing up things like Initialization Vectors, keys, etc.

Comment: This is great. I found threefish from Ferguson and Schneider way much simpler. Coleage of mine spent 2months to port AES on freescale processor and running 5% faster. That code was unimaginable cryptic. (just like algorhitm)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a working implementation check out the [Rijndael Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael.aspx) on MSDN. The Rijndael implementation looks pretty convenient to interface with.

It's of course a different story if you are trying implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking into the same that as per brian.
But the problem here is that all the rijndael samples available in the net are mostly using a Text File but is there any way of doing it in a Online Mode where when i get the data in the text box i convert it and put directly in to the database.

Any Hints on this would be much better and all the samples are defining the key from the Rijndael class itself, can't we provide the Key of our own.

cheers
Biju